# Drawing polylines within waypoint

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have use [google_directions_api: ^0.5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/google_directions_api) this flutter library for implement google Direction api.

```
await directinosService.route(request,
        (DirectionsResult response, DirectionsStatus status) {
        if (status == DirectionsStatus.ok) {

          for(GeoCoord value in response.routes.asMap().values.single.overviewPath){
            _polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(value.latitude,value.longitude));
          }
        } else {
          print('Im not in ok state');
          // do something with error response
        }
      });

Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      width: 4,
      visible: true,
      polylineId: PolylineId(_latitude.toString()),
      color: (randomColour.toList()..shuffle()).first,
      points: _polylineCoordinates
  );
  _polylines.add(polyline);
```

i get tha polyline but its not clear when zoom some points are away from road
[when zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEzey.png) [Zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqamP.png)

[I need implement Google map like this with flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqa6o.png) 
I found Flutter lib but its not clear to me

if someone can help me how i exactly get waypoints to recorrect polyline